# Serializing Request.Form to a Dictionary or something

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Hi i need to pass my Request.Form as a parameter, but first i have to add some key/value pairs to it. I get the exception that the Collection is readonly.

I've tried:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection myform = Request.Form;
```

and i get the same error.

and i've tried:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in Request.Form)
{
     Response.Write(Convert.ToString(pair.Key) + " - " + Convert.ToString(pair.Value) + "<br />");
}
```

to test if i can pass it one by one to another dictionary, but i get:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified
>   cast is not valid.

some help, anyone? Thanx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need to cast a `string` to `string`. `NameValueCollection` is built around string keys, and string values.  How about a quick extension method:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection col)
{
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  foreach (var key in col.Keys)
  {
    dict.Add(key, col[key]);
  }

  return dict;
}
```

That way you can easily go:

```
var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary();
dict.Add("key", "value");
```

Comment: thanx Matthew, i'm going to try it tomorrow. I went with hidden fields for the time being.

Comment: matthew - nice one (and +1). being a scot, couldn't resist my stab at this below using a little LINQ :). happy new year - parf... :-) (btw, having a little read of your blog just now, liking the regula and javascript linq articles) 
btw, you might wanna review this javascript LINQ implementation http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 16):

If your already using MVC then you can do it with 0 lines of code.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Request.Form.CopyTo(dictionary);
```

Answer (score 3):

Andre,

how about:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection myform = Request.Form; 

IDictionary<string, string> myDictionary = 
    myform.Cast<string>()
           .Select(s => new { Key = s, Value = myform[s] })
           .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

uses LINQ to keep it all on one 'line'. this could be exrapolated to an extension method of:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection col)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (col != null)
    {
        myDictionary =
            col.Cast<string>()
                .Select(s => new { Key = s, Value = col[s] })
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    }
    return myDictionary;
}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: hee hee, aye - :). i do sometimes overdo it with linq. in fact, i've got a dilema as i've been offered a new opportunity that has to be provisioned on the LAMP stack and am wondering how i'll cope in php5 objects without linq :) 
(tho i did see this http://phplinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: NameValueCollection needs to be NameValueCollection

Answer (score 3):

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ToEnumerable(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    return collection
      //.Keys
        .Cast<string>()
        .Select(key => new Tuple<string, string>(key, collection[key]));
}
```

or

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    return collection
      //.Keys
        .Cast<string>()
        .ToDictionary(key => key, key => collection[key]));
}
```